# pass an array to SQL query through PDO Params to search IN array

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, pdo, parameters

I don't know exactly how to title this question, however I became aware of risks of SQL injection and I am modifying a query to use a prepared statement.

In the original query I was passing an array of ids to look for in the DB like this:

```
AND item.id IN ($ids)
```

where for example

```
$ids = "35,36,69,73,98,218,219,234,242";
```

Now I modified the query so I put that data into `$params` like this:

```
$params = [':ids' => $ids ];
```

and modified the line in the query to:

```
AND item.id IN (:ids)
```

so I execute the query like this:

```
$query->execute($params);
```

However by dumping `$query` I can see that the ids are not passed and this is what passes instead:

```
IN (:ids)
```

So obviously nothing is retrieved.

Comment: What flavor of SQL rdbms? If it's SQL Server check out "Table Valued Parameters".

Comment: I am using mySQL

Comment: There's [answers like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition) which help address that deficiency in PDO.

Comment: I tried the solution, I get `SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined`

Comment: If you're creating that list of IDs, and you know they're integers, why not simply put them literally in the query? That's the simplest solution, it won't fail, it's not vulnerable, and it takes 1 line to write if you are already sure you have integers.

Comment: Yes you are right. I was overthinking. Anyway I will also try other solutions.